# Is there an issue with this UUID generation code?

Tags: c++, random, uuid

So I have some code which needs to use UUID for database IDs. I've gone with v4 (random) for simplicity's sake, and I don't see any real reason to use any of the other less random version of UUID. My UUID class is approximately defined like this (simplified):

```
class uuid {
public:
    static uuid create_v4();
public:
    // cut out for simplification...
public:
    uint8_t bytes[16];
};
```

where the actual generation code looks like this:

```
namespace {

uint32_t rand32() {
    // we need to do this, because there is no
    // gaurantee that RAND_MAX is >= 0xffffffff
    // in fact, it is LIKELY to be 0x7fffffff
    const uint32_t r1 = rand() & 0x0ff;
    const uint32_t r2 = rand() & 0xfff;
    const uint32_t r3 = rand() & 0xfff;
    return (r3 << 20) | (r2 << 8) | r1;

}

}

uuid uuid::create_v4() {

    static const uint16_t c[] = {
        0x8000,
        0x9000,
        0xa000,
        0xb000,
    };

    uuid uuid;

    const uint32_t rand_1 = (rand32() & 0xffffffff);
    const uint32_t rand_2 = (rand32() & 0xffff0fff) | 0x4000;
    const uint32_t rand_3 = (rand32() & 0xffff0fff) | c[rand() & 0x03];
    const uint32_t rand_4 = (rand32() & 0xffffffff);

    uuid.bytes[0x00] = (rand_1 >> 24) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x01] = (rand_1 >> 16) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x02] = (rand_1 >> 8 ) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x03] = (rand_1      ) & 0xff;

    uuid.bytes[0x04] = (rand_2 >> 24) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x05] = (rand_2 >> 16) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x06] = (rand_2 >> 8 ) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x07] = (rand_2      ) & 0xff;

    uuid.bytes[0x08] = (rand_3 >> 24) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x09] = (rand_3 >> 16) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x0a] = (rand_3 >> 8 ) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x0b] = (rand_3      ) & 0xff;

    uuid.bytes[0x0c] = (rand_4 >> 24) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x0d] = (rand_4 >> 16) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x0e] = (rand_4 >> 8 ) & 0xff;
    uuid.bytes[0x0f] = (rand_4      ) & 0xff;

    return uuid;
}
```

This **looks** correct to me, but I recently got an error from the DB saying that the UUID I tried to insert was a duplicate. Since this is supposed to be highly improbable, I have to assume that there may be an issue with my code. So anyone see anything wrong? Is my random UUID generation, not quite random enough?

**NOTE:** I cannot use boost's random number generation or it's UUID library. I wish I could, but I am tied to a particular system with particular versions of libraries installed and getting a new enough version of boost to have those features is pretty much not possible.

Comment: How are you seeding `rand()`?

Comment: Using a plain `rand()` for this stuff doesn't seem such a good idea to me, especially since the low-order bits of numbers generated by an LCG are the *least* random part of the generated number (they typically have shorter period). You should *at the very least* take some higher order bits, and if I were you I'd go with the version of the algorithm that includes a timestamp, at least you are much less likely to generate duplicates.

Comment: You should check the value of RAND_MAX. I've just been bitten by a bug where RAND_MAX was 2^15 (which is the minimum guaranteed size) and I was trying to index into a container with ~60k entries.

Comment: can you let the database generate it itself? That would be the safest bet.

Comment: Good questions: @Keith: I am seeding with `srand(time(0));` once at program start. I am considering using `/dev/[u]random` instead if it would help. @Rook: look at my `rand32` function which is designed to specifically address that. @pstrjds: I hadn't thought of that, it seems that mysql has a `UUID()` function. though this would mean an extra trip to the DB, it may be worth it for correctness.

Comment: @Matteo: as far as I understand, the gnu libc's implementation of `rand()` takes measures to avoid the LCG having lower randomness, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Seeding with `time()` has a 1-second resolution.  Could you be running the seed code more than once in the same second?

Comment: @Keith: It shouldn't unless something goes VERY wrong, the code it run once every 5 minutes via a cron task.

Comment: @EvanTeran: If you have `/dev/urandom` you could also just read 16 bytes from it directly...

Comment: @KennyTM: true, but it is my understanding that it is bad to "drain the entropy pool" like that. correct me if i'm wrong of course.

Comment: @pst: do you find that my UUID generation code deviates from the format of a V4 UUID? In what way is it invalid? As for library, any recommendations?

Comment: @EvanTeran: Well it seems you are just generating 1 UUID per 5 minutes which I doubt it would drain the pool... Anyway, maybe you could check whether `<tr1/random>` (or even `<random>`) exists, which provides some better RNGs with a known range.

Comment: @EvanTeran: You can also check whether `<uuid.h>` exists and use `uuid_generate_random()`. (but note that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759410/uuid-generate-random-libuuid-on-solaris.)

Comment: @KennyTM: the program is run every 5 minutes, but each run generates many (let's say 1000) UUIDs. I don't think tr1 is available, but it's worth checking, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @EvanTeran - I don't think it deviates, I just don't think rand() has a long enough cycle length. UUID's generally use seeding from MAC addresses and other things to ensure uniqueness. I don't know what libraries to use. In my case I work in a windows environment and there are win API functions for generating UUIDs. In general when I am pushing data into a database I let the database generate the UUID and then just get the result via the query output (SQL Server).

Comment: @pstrjds: there actually was a user named "pst" who did claim it was invalid, and then said I should use a "proper library" he has subsequently removed his comment :-).

Comment: As for the DB generation of UUIDs, I would prefer to be able to generate them offline. because I use the UUID has a foreign key. 1 entry which has a UUID, then in another table I insert maybe 20 rows which refer to the first table via the UUID. Having the DB create the UUID means I would have to either have a specific `SELECT` to get a UUID and then do the inserts, or generate it during initial `INSERT` and somehow get the UUID from the newly created record (which isn't quite as simple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code appears to be reasonable to me.  As mentioned in the comments, there is some question as to whether rand() is a good choice for this task, but your usage of it seems like a reasonable way to produce 32-bits of data assuming a newer version of the library is being used that ensures the lower bits are as random as the higher bits (also mentioned in the comments by you).

So as long as the rand() function is doing even a moderately good job, it seems very unlikely that you should get a duplicate.  So my guess is that there was a different kind of failure. Some possibilities that come to mind:

1. time(0) failure.  This seems highly unlikely.  If it returned -1 to indicate an error in two different runs, then it could lead to the problem.  However, the only way it is supposed to be able to fail is if an invalid address was given to it (which is definitely not the case here).
2. Multi-threaded usage.  I don't think rand() is thread-safe.  If this code were used in a multi-threaded situation, maybe that could result in unexpected behavior.
3. Cron is causing difficulties.  If the clock on the workstation were not accurate and it was being set automatically (e.g., via rdate) to sync with some server, then it could cause a repeat in the cron job at a certain time.  I was able to mimic this behavior simply by creating a cron job to dump the current date to a file every minute and then repeatedly setting the date ... it ended up writing the same date/time (to the second) to the file more than once.  With a one second resolution of the time function, this could easily lead to a duplicate seed.
4. The code writing the UUID to the database is incorrect.  Even if the UUID generator is working perfectly, there could be a different bug that writes the same UUID twice to the database.

Just wild guesses.  Of these, the third one is my favorite, but the 4th would be the one I would suspect first if I were reviewing my own code.

Comment: #3 is very interesting, I'll definitely have to check into that. I've since updated the code to use `/dev/urandom` for the seed when it can be successfully read and falls back on `time(0)` if that fails. So far, it's looking good.

Comment: @Evan: Last Friday afternoon while waiting for some code scans to complete (that are sucking the life and soul out of me), I played with your UUID generation routine in both Windows and Linux.  I simply generated 10 million of them, dumped them to a file, sorted, and then looked for duplicates via awk or ruby (can't remember right now) and did not produce duplicates.  Not that that test really proves anything, but I failed to find anything wrong with the logic in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in getting to the bottom of this. The code has been running well for a few weeks now and I only got the duplicate key error once. So it truly may have been just really bad luck i guess.

Comment: I am accepting this answer since I think that the problem was point #3. I altered the code to see with `/dev/random` and only use `time(0)` if that fails. There have been no more collisions since. Thanks again.